# Issuing building a table using JS function and Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to build and display a table based on an array. I've searched around for a fair while and can't seem to find an answer as to why my code isn't working.

it's a simple function call with an array being passed in via the function parameter, but for some reason it comes up as undefined as it seems the array doesn't get pass through to the function parameter.

A basic summary of my code is below:

```
    <div id="myDiv"></div>

    <script>

    function myFunction(tableData){
       var table = document.createElement('table');
       var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

       tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
           var row = document.createElement('tr');
           rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
           var cell = document.createElement('td');
           cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
           row.appendChild(cell);
           });

       tableBody.appendChild(row);
       });

       table.appendChild(tableBody);
   };

    var array1 = {key1:"value1",key2:"value2",key3:"value3"};

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myFunction(array1);

    </script>
```

EDIT: This one is solved. Thanks comments!

Comment: Your "array" isn't actually an array, it's an object, which means you can't call `.forEach()` on it because that is an array method. You should be seeing an error in the browser's dev console that says something like "tableData.forEach is not a function". It looks like what your function is actually expecting is an array of arrays like `[['val1', 'val2'], ['val3', 'val4'], ['val5', 'val6']]`. Also, your function doesn't return a value.

Comment: You will have to try `for..in`

Comment: `rowData.forEach` will also expect an array of object

Comment: Ahhhhhh of course. I should have used for....in. Stupid me!

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do with this line

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myFunction(array1);
```

i cant find any return from your function which set the inner html of the div.

```
var array1 = {key1:"value1",key2:"value2",key3:"value3"};
```

and your array is an object.

try fixing these issue first.

try doing this..

```
    <script>

    function myFunction(tableData){
       var table = document.createElement('table');
       var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

       tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
           var row = document.createElement('tr');
           rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
           var cell = document.createElement('td');
           cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
           row.appendChild(cell);
           });

       tableBody.appendChild(row);
       });

       table.appendChild(tableBody);

      return table;
   };

    </script>
```

Comment: Nicely spotted for return statement

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put your *HTML/JS/CSS*  code and make it executable

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
for(var i in array1) {
    console.log(i); //this will print key1, key2...
    console.log(array1[i]); //this will print value1, value2...
}
```

The error you're getting is because your data is a javascript object, and not a javascript array. So `forEach` wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need

- an array for the data,
- return the table, and
- use `appendChild`, for getting the table assigned to the div, because you are working with DOM elements and not using strings (strings works with `innerHTML`).

```js
function myFunction(tableData) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

    tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
            row.appendChild(cell);
        });
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    });
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    return table;
}

var array1 = [["value1", "value2", "value3"], ["value4", "value5", "value6"], ["value7", "value8", "value9"]];

document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myFunction(array1));
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: worth mentioning that it's `appendChild` getting it worked and not `innerHTML`. Would like to know why though!